# Angular 5 remove class from siblings

Tags: angular, angular-renderer2

I am trying to create a navbar with multiple hyper links in angular. I want to add class 'active' on click/hover of any of the hyper links and remove 'active' class from its siblings. I am trying to do this by creating a custom directive.

This is what I have achieved.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
   selector: '[AppHighlightActiveMenu]'
})
export class HighlightMenuDirective {

constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

@HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
   this.activate();
}

@HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {

}

private activate() {
  this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'active'); 
}

private deactivate(element: ElementRef) {
  console.log("Element: ", element);
}
}
```

I am able to add the active class to the element but cannot remove the already existing active class from the siblings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a `removeClass`?

```
 removeClass(className: string, element: any) {
   this.renderer.removeClass(element, className);
}
```

But for a navbar  why do you not use a `<router-outlet>` with `routerLinkActive="active"` for your links, where is the default builtin directive for that use in Angular.